# Applying num2words to a list of integers

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am trying to apply the num2words function to the list of integers for french language.

```
from num2words import num2words

import random 

list= replacement_nums = [random.randint(6,50) for _ in range(20)]
```

and for that I am trying the map function like this:

```
num2letter = lambda x: x.num2words()


changed_list = list(map(num2letter, list)); changed_list
```

but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'num2words'
```

I have previously done mapping on a list of strings, and tried to use upper case and it worked, but I am not sure why it does not work on integers

Comment: `list(map(num2words, list))`, also you should name your list not as the reserved word `list` but e.g. `my_list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from num2words import num2words
import random

replacement_nums = [random.randint(6, 50) for _ in range(20)]

num2letter = lambda x: num2words(x, lang='fr')

changed_list = list(map(num2letter, replacement_nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the right function, just use it with `map`.

```
list(map(num2words, your_list))
```

Comment: I guess neither of this will work as he overwrote the `list` function with his `list` variable, see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

(based on previous replies and just for future reference)

If you want to write it in one line using `list comprehension`, write:

```
  changed_list =[num2words(x,lang= 'fr') for x in my_list]; changed_list
```